# Custom ASP.NET Core Middleware with cancellation Token

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a custom ASP.NET Core middleware and I want to retrieve the cancellation token for the request.

I tried to add it to the signature of the invoke like this:

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context,CancellationToken token)
```

But as soon as I add it, it isn't called any more.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think the idea is not to be able to cancel invocation of the middleware, from inside the middleware if you call some async task that accepts a cancellation token then you can create one and pass it in to what you are calling from inside there.

A common scenario would be to cancel a task if the request is aborted, so you could create the token like this:

```
CancellationToken CancellationToken => context?.RequestAborted ?? CancellationToken.None;
```

and then call some async service like getting data or querying the db, if the request is aborted then the cancellation request should happen

Comment: I agree, but please note: CancellationToken is a struct, and HttpContext.RequestAborted is not a nullable, so will never be null. Therefore the null-coalescing operator (??) is not appropriate and will not compile.

Comment: The null check is because of `context?.` so it can be null in the case context is null.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can catch it in case of operation cancel inside your exception handling middleware like this:

```
catch(OperationCanceledException ex) when (ex.CancellationToken == context.RequestAborted) { // log here}
```